# the physics of absorbing a laser's beam through contact of mirrors

Tags: thermodynamics

If you were to set out multiple mirrors or even double sided mirrors how many Times would it have to reflect to be completely absorbed into heat by the lasers??

Comment: How good are your mirrors? With really good ones you can reflect beams forth and back thousands of times.